# how to avoid using the same condition twice in slim views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have the following code in my view:

```
.container
  .row
    .col
      h3 Header
      - if @status < 5
        p Text
    - if @status < 5
      .col
        p More text
```

As you can see I use the same condition two times because of slim indentation. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you want to change this only for "better-looking" purposes or is there some performance issue also?

Comment: Its common to have this kind of situation, an not that bad. The most concerning thing here is the magic number `5` which should be at least: `@status < SOME_CONSTANT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is nothing wrong with this markup, so the best solution here is to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think you can do is refactor it.

Use a helper instead of hardcoded condition everywhere, so that when you decide to change `5` to `6` you will have to make the change at one place only.

**Helper method**

```
def valid_status?(status)
  status < 5
end
```

**view (slim)**

```
.container
  .row
    .col
      h3 Header
      - if valid_status?(@status)
        p Text
    - if valid_status?(@status)
      .col
        p More text
```

Or at least assign the value to a variable once

```
- valid_status = @status < 5
.container
  .row
    .col
      h3 Header
      - if valid_status
        p Text
    - if valid_status
      .col
        p More text
```

Comment: It is more or less the same as in the question. :)

Comment: anyway you can't change the html structure so it has to be same

Comment: the only change is the way you are using the conditions. In this case by using helper method you avoid the problem of having to change the condition at 2-3 places

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the conditional to a helper like Deepak suggested and use a `partial render` to extract the html snippet. More or less like this:

```
.container
  .row
    .col
      h3 Header
        = render "render_text_1" if status_5? # Humanize status code to be more clear
    .col
      = render "render_text_2" if status_5?
```